# Regular expressions. Search for words without repeating numbers

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, char, fstream

I need to write the code that will output words without repeating digits. By assignment, I have to use the char array. I decided to do this with regular expressions. At the moment I have this expression:

```
regex rx ("^(?!.*(.).*\1)[0-9]+$");
```

If you take each word of the string separately, then regex works, but if you write all the words in the string separated by a space, then regex does not work. How can i fix this?

Input file: 1234567890 987 787

The code must output at least 1234567890, because this is the first match, and it does not output anything

Full code:

```
int main() {

    regex rx ("^(?!.*(.).*\1)[0-9]+$");
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("input.txt");
    int counter = 0;
    char ch;
    while (ch = fin.get() != EOF)
    {
        counter++;
    }
    cout << counter << "\n";
    fin.close();
    fin.open("input.txt");
    char *str = new char [counter];
    fin.getline(str, counter, '\0');
    fin.close();
    cmatch res;

    std::regex_search(str, res, rx);
        std::cout << res[0] << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your regex must match begin and end of the string, and it must not contain any characters other than digits (because of the negative lookahead). https://regex101.com/r/UZ3WI6/1

Comment: What is a word without a repeating digit? Can you give some examples?

Comment: ```\``` need to be escaped in string, either use ```\\1``` or raw string `R"(\1)"`.

Comment: You probably want `regex rx (R"(^(?!.*(.).*\1)\d(?:\s*\d)*$)");` (if there can be any amount of whitespace between every digit, but no leading/trailing whitespace is allowed).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: [seems not](https://regex101.com/r/8jdQy1/1).

Comment: @Jarod42 You did not test correctly (using PCRE setting with a multiline input). See the correct test at https://regex101.com/r/8jdQy1/2.

Comment: If the spaces are literal spaces and you need to match *lines* in a multiline text, just use `regex rx (R"(^(?!.*(.).*\1)\d(?: *\d)*$)");` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/8jdQy1/4))

Comment: @Hi - I love SO 
for example:
1234567890
No number is repeated - one or no repetition

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew unlimited number of spaces is allowed

Comment: So, does my last comment solution work? `regex rx (R"(^(?!.*(.).*\1)\d(?: *\d)*$)");`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Unfortunately not. There must be 2 matches in this line(1234567890 987)
https://regex101.com/r/xdGwiV/1

Comment: Ah, you need `\b(?!\d*(\d)\d*\1)\d+\b`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank u so much! But how can I use this for a char array? (sry for stupid questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```cpp
\b(?!\d*(\d)\d*\1)\d+\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/il1qmx/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\d*(\d)\d*\1)` - no repeating digits allowed in the number
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\b` - a word boundary

See the [online C++ demo](https://ideone.com/8BTGic):

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::regex r(R"(\b(?!\d*(\d)\d*\1)\d+\b)");
    char *str = "1234567890 987 787";

    for (cregex_iterator it(str, str + strlen(str), r); it != cregex_iterator{}; it++)
    {
        cout << (*it).str() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be `1234567890` and `987`.

Comment: Thank u so much! But how can I use this for a char array? (sry for stupid questions)

Comment: Thank u sooooooooooo much!Where can I read about regex in great detail, so as not to ask stupid questions in the future?

Comment: @Tamada See [this post](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/wstribizew/my-regex-road-so-far).